# Phonegap - Does Phonegap use HTTP:// or file://?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working on a phonegap build app and I was wondering if phonegap loads pages using http or file.
I'm trying to use a bunch of iframes and it matters a lot as you can imagine.
Otherwise, what would be another way?

:)
ProBroRLZ

Comment: Another way to do what? To access content? What kind of content are you looking at?

Comment: `alert(window.location.protocol);` will tell you.

Comment: Calls to the backend (CORS/AJAX) from PhoneGap (at  least on PHP) will always be file://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ProBroRLZ,
if you are loading HTML pages (or images) for the WebView, then you need to use `http://` or path relative. (`file://` is generally not useful, depending on the platform)

If you are loading files, then it depends on what they are used for. Generally, you need to use a plugin.

As such,

- for general use, use the File plugin.
- for media (audio, video, images), use the Media or Camera plugin.

For specifics on how to read a file, you need to read the docs. Each platform treats the file space differently, and each plugin treats files differently. Make no assumptions with plugins, read the docs or ask the author.

Since you are new to this I recommend the following:

https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/explanation-of-phonegapcordova-for-the-layman/
https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/which-programming-language-should-i-learn-to-make-apps/

and

*Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md
Especially #1, #2, & #5

Best of Luck
Jesse

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jesse. However, I am using a relative path so will phonegap load the files with http or file? In other words, will I be able to use the function 'parent.(functionname)' from the iframe? I am also aware that phonegap does not support server-end languages like PHP, Python, etc. and these have to be used with ajax

Comment: Okay. There are several ways to get files on Phonegap Build, 1) use the webview interface, which allows you to fetch a file and view a file in the webview. When doing this you are using relative path. With webview you can use alternate (or third-party) replacemenst - like [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) or [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/landing/cocoonjs-phonegap/).

Comment: If you want to process and save the file (or upload it), you will want to use the [HTML5 File interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), or the [Phonegap File Plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1164) (that does the same). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: But with these methods, can I reference the parent page with the parent.(stuff) type of things? Are they gonna be considered to be on the same domain?

Comment: Ok guys thank you very much for all the info. I ended up spending half an hour copying my code from the iframes to the main html so now its irrelevant. However, since your answer was most informative I mark this as correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

None of them. Basically the phonegap app works as a web app (or a website if you prefer), so you do in the same fashion: folder/file_name.ext (e.g. views/home.html). http/https are required if the file/page you are trying to load is not included into your phonegap project and is loaded externally.

Comment: So loading a localised iframe will not be 'on the same domain'?